# WPF :: how to drag and drop labels

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to achieve drag and drop on labels to a grid on my app, i don't know how should i do that, should i use normal mouse events? is there anything special that will make my life easier in WPF?

i'm not asking for a solution, i read tons of WPF example, but all talking about Dragging files to my app, but i found nothing about dragging Controls to a Grid on something like that can you help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i have understand your right... try this: [http://vijaykamat.blogspot.com](http://vijaykamat.blogspot.com/2010/12/drag-and-drop.html)

Comment: This link is now dead.